# How to intercept an HTTP redirect response in Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

I have a Power App and Power Automate solution integrated with Docusign using their REST API's.

My issue is that I have users log into Docusign from a link which when completed and authenticated, returns an https response (authorization code) on the redirect uri. I want to be able to 'capture' the authorization code within Power Automate.

I want to avoid using custom connectors as they seem unreliable when using Oauth2 authentication and the users access token has expired. My preference is to use the HTTP REST API steps in Power Automate instead.

With a redirect to  https://localhost:3000/auth/docusign/callback, I get the following https response:

```
https://localhost:3000/auth/docusign/callback?code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQoAAAABAAYABwAAlzFclSfZSAgAACO4o5Un2UgCAOid-3Oz8jJHsDvIUG5hRR8VAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAZjA5Y2U4NDQtM2U5Yy00NjEzLTkwNzctNGY5MmFhY2NjZTc4IgAkAAAAZjA5Y2U4NDQtM2U5Yy00NjEzLTkwNzctNGY5MmFhY2NjZTc4NwBBDjKOCdhvSaNUWiI7O-21MAAAkAfAlCfZSA.zrYv2gsNFPVWHZpoO7-_5o4Ika3DxQpbNqlPUHiOvYFVL5igRnbZHh2V7OmN0bff7Tf14QF3pWaBAATozpIgzgj21m3ZjLbhY5J42eR1msXmoXjbBggibGC_FqbprVCzjSCvjbvMlwgEwda7LApdSWwr49ON9KhdN84qWD9sacJJvdi3Oi1KInImlVB_2rTpCLFhMD98PBv6b074yTqLOfwV31QT-6si8xLtk3G2vtn2gFZigXQxIA18b6tC-BM3NOILV1zwZNa1pstxxG2W8jJByUQlAux3d1GuS4vnDu_nr54mXULV0vY7txLFRiJA5w_E7Nlu2dlaOa5_DmfpNg
```

I want to intercept the **code=eyJ0e........** in my flow.

I have tried setting up an http request and using the unique endpoint, used that as a redirect endpoint to send it to a receiving HTTP request flow. Docusign did not like the http request URL as a redirect.

I have to think this is a very simple thing to do and probably has to do with how the redirect/callback is configured in Power Automate.  There maybe third party solutions that can act as a redirect intermediary which I can then GET with an API call. All ideas appreciated.

Comment: Does your flow contact the API via an HTTP request, or does the power-app literally open windows and have them do everything there? I ask because if it's the flow that is doing all the logging in, etc, via the HTTP Request action, then you can use the HTTP Response as the next step (or later) to capture any response to the request. Might also be worth looking up if you can log users in via the API yourself using your developer token. If so, then you can almost certainly design something with this in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I can include an HTTP request to contact the API, however, I get HTML reply and unable to open any window to execute in PowerApps unless I am missing something. I have investigated iframe for PowerApps however do not have credentials to include iframe add on in Power Apps. I would have to think there is a method to do this within Power Apps. I have tried changing redirect to a power automate webhook but Docusign does not like the uri for the webhook as a redirection end point.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didn't express that quite fully. There is a Power Automate action called "HTTP Response" ... look for that and add it later on in the flow to send information BACK to the API. So ... when the API calls your flow via the long URL, the flow will automatically use the RESPONSE action to send whatever relevant data you need back to the requesting entity. Sorry I don't have a link to documentation, it's not written about a lot, to be honest!